# how to tell if a property exists and is false

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, jquery-templates

I am having a hard time determining if data passed into the jquery template exists and is false without getting errors. This is what I am using to test

```
<html>
<head>
<title>jQuery Templates {{if}} logic</title>
</head>
<body>

<p id="results"></p>
<p>How do you test if the Value exists and is false?</p>

<script id="testTemplate" type="text/html">

    Test ${Test}:

    {{if Value}}
        Value exists and is true
    {{else}}
        Value doesn't exist or is false
    {{/if}}

    <br/>

</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.tmpl.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#testTemplate").tmpl({Test:1}).appendTo("#results");
        $("#testTemplate").tmpl({Test:2, Value:true}).appendTo("#results");
        $("#testTemplate").tmpl({Test:3, Value:false}).appendTo("#results");
    });
</script>

</body></html>
```

Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use another `else` statement in there using a `=== false` check, like this:

```
{{if Value}}
    Value exists and is true
{{else typeof(Value) != "undefined" && Value === false}}
    Value exists and is false
{{else}}
    Value doesn't exist or isn't explicitly false
{{/if}}
```

[You can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/gj9p9/). The `typeof` check is because you'll get a `Value is not defined` error with *only* `Value === false`.  You would add other checks as well, for example `{{else typeof(Value) == "undefined"}}` would be true if the value wasn't specified.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a function to check for you:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function isExplicitlyFalse(f) { return f === false; }

    $("#testTemplate").tmpl({Test:1, isExplicitlyFalse: isExplicitlyFalse}).appendTo("#results");
    $("#testTemplate").tmpl({Test:2, Value:true, isExplicitlyFalse: isExplicitlyFalse}).appendTo("#results");
    $("#testTemplate").tmpl({Test:3, Value:false, isExplicitlyFalse: isExplicitlyFalse}).appendTo("#results");
});
```

then in your template:

```
{{if item.isExplicitlyFalse(Value)}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thow it this question is a bit old here is anoter possible solution.
You can also use the [Logical AND](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND);

E.g:

```
if ( value && !value ) {
 // if value is defined and equals false
}
```