# how to tell if a subproperty exists in jquery tmpl

Tags: jquery, json, templates

I have a similar issue like this one: [see link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3901641/how-to-tell-if-a-property-exists-and-is-false)

What I need to determine if a given **SUBproperty** exists. My json looks like this

```
{
    "nodeX": {
        "sub_node1": {
            "items": {
                "A": "something",
                "B": "etc"
            }
        },
        "sub_node2": {
            "items": {
                "A": "another thing",
                "B": "blablabla",
                "C": {
                    "top": 50,
                    "left": 75
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I make an IF statement to see if nodeX.sub_node2.items.C exists?

If I do this I get errors:
{{if ${nodeX.sub_node2.items.C }} ... {{/if}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IF statement goes like this:

```
{{if typeof nodeX.sub_node2.items.C !== "undefined"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you attempt to access a non-existent property on an `Object`, `undefined` is returned, of which of course will never have any properties.

You need to construct this convoluted check...

```
if (nodeX && nodeX.sub_node2 && nodeX.sub_node2.items && nodeX.sub_node2.items.C) {

}
```

Comment: alex, thanks for your answer. unfortunatelly it didn't work...at least as an IF statement in jquery templates. I'll later post a jsfiddle to play around

Answer (score 0):

jQuery templates uses the JavaScript with() notation for the top level object (your data context), so to test that, you have to use

```
typeof nodeX === 'undefined' ? valueIfUndefined : nodeX
```

Then to check for the existence of a subobject, you should be able to do

```
('sub_node1' in nodeX) ? 'yes!' : 'no!'
```

If you're just conditionally displaying the properties, you can actually skip checking them yourself and just do

```
${items.A}${items.C}
```

because the framework is actually doing these checks for you as it fills the template. If the properties don't exist, it doesn't try to execute the statements.